# Symfony 2.1.4 - Dynamic routing with parameters.yml

Tags: dynamic, symfony, symfony-2.1, routes

I have this error

> No route found for "GET /sn/"

and this .. in parameters.yml

```
parameters:  
[...]  
    client_abv:         sn
```

And my routing.yml file :

```
_internal:  
  resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
  prefix: /_internal

ClientResultBundle_Admin:
    resource: "@ClientResultBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin.yml"
    prefix: /%client_abv%/admin

ClientResultBundle_PointDeVente:
    resource: "@ClientResultBundle/Resources/config/routing/pointdevente.yml"
    prefix: /%client_abv%/pointdevente

ClientResultBundle_Sn:
    resource: "@ClientResultBundle/Resources/config/routing/sn.yml"
    prefix:   /%client_abv%

ClientResultBundle:
    resource: "@ClientResultBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /%client_abv%
```

So why the command console `route:match /sn/` works and not in the browser ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you look at the config file, the resource for the router points at routing.yml, but routing.yml is never exposed to any other resources inside your config.yml.

Comment: it doesn't take into account the import of parameters.yml ? hmm. This page let me thinks that it is possible ... http://symfony.com/fr/doc/master/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html

Comment: Oh. You're right. I just tried it out and it seems to work only for "pattern:" but not for "prefix:"

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of ending slash - point to `/sn`.

Comment: It's the same. Pointing to /sn gives me No route found for "GET /sn"